# Listing all columns in all tables that contain email address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse

For GDPR requirements, we want to delete all rows in our Redshift cluster that are linked to a deletion requestor's email address. Our warehouse schemas changes frequently and new fields are added by many parties, sometimes without adequate documentation. High level, I want a solution that can pull all the columns that contain email addresses and check if the email of the requestor is listed.

My initial approach to this was to generate a list of all varchar/text columns on all tables for all non pg_* schemas, using this query:

```
    SELECT 
        t.table_schema, t.table_name
    FROM 
        information_schema.tables t
    WHERE t.table_schema NOT LIKE 'pg_%'  
          AND t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
    ORDER BY t.table_schema, t.table_name;
```

and then, I wrote a script to iteratively check each column individually for the count of rows that contained an "@" character. I highlight these columns as the "email-containing" columns and export them to a CSV. I then have another script that iterates through and deletes all rows where the email matches any of these columns for each table.

This approach works, but it feels naive. I would think I could capture the list of email containing columns in a dynamic view or window function.

What is a better approach to solving this problem?

Comment: There are services such as [Amazon Macie - Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com/macie/) that can search for Personally Identifiable Information, and they basically do the same process as your script -- they dump the data, then look for PII-like data. If your process is working, then keep using it! (You could look for `@.*\.`, which would be a better match than just `@`.)

Comment: What do you mean by "Our warehouse schemas changes frequently" ?